# How to Read a TXT file in Java Server Page Directory

Tags: java, jsp, web

I'd like to create an app that requires to read a `.txt` file on my project directory.

This is my code of my `index.jsp`:

```
<%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Read Text</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("aFile.txt"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            out.println(sb.toString());
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I execute the above code, my browser tells me that `aFile.txt` cannot be found. Then, I've put `aFile.txt` in the same directory as this web page runs (`index.jsp`).
I wonder, what should I write to locate the directory of `aFile.txt`

And this is how my problem was solved. Thanks Ahmad hasem

```
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStreamReader"%>
<%@page import="java.net.URL"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Read Text</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String jspPath = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/res");
            String txtFilePath = jspPath+ "/aFile.txt";
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFilePath));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            out.println(sb.toString());
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to locate it from application's root path.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/ReadingBinaryData.htm

Answer (score 6):

To get the directory of the running JSP, you can call the following code :

```
String jspPath = session.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

This code assumes that the JSP resides on the root of your web application. Then, you can append the txt file name to the `jspPath`

```
String txtFilePath = jspPath + java.util.File.separator + "aFile.txt";
```

Comment: so close. But I cannot find getServletConfig, can you help me ?

Comment: @farissyariati just try `session.getServletContext()...`

Answer (score 2):

where is jsp file and text file.are you put both in web-inf folder.please remove txt file from web-inf because you are need servlet if you want to access txt file from web-inf.

use the below code for get the path of the text file.

```
       this
      .getServlet()
      .getServletContext()
      .getRealPath(FOLDER NAME)
      .concat(System.getProperty("file.separator")
      .concat(FILE NAME));
```

pass the above code in file object.

Comment: Yes, i put it on web-inf. What if I put it on outside web-inf ? for example I make a folder and put it there.

Answer (score 0):

You should not assume that the file can be read using the file system. It is a deployment and implementation detail as to whether the WAR file is "exploded" or not.

Assuming that `aFile.txt` is in the root of your application, you should be able to open the stream [using the servlet context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29):

```
<% java.io.InputStream in = application.getResourceAsStream("/aFile.txt"); %>
```

There are also more appropriate ways to inline other files into a JSP.

The JSP include [standard action](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28961/genlovw.htm#i1006026):

```
<jsp:include page="aFile.txt" />
```

The [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) import tag:

```
<%-- header --%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
....
<c:import url="/aFile.txt" />
```

*I am assuming this code is being written for educational purposes. No modern application should include `<% %>` scriptlets.*

Comment: About your last statement, how should them be done then? Any reference please? Thanks in advance

Comment: @BtcSources I assume you are talking about my comment on scriptlets. [BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882) has a page on this: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I have experienced it will read from the root directory of your webserver. Actually from the directory you started the webserver. In Tomcat it will be /home/mike/tomcat. Naturally, because it was from this directory you started your java virtual machine and java will consider this its root directory.